# Difference between feature_column.embedding_column and keras.layers.Embedding in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, input, deep-learning, embedding

I have been using **keras.layers.Embedding** for almost all of my projects. But, recently I wanted to fiddle around with tf.data and found **feature_column.embedding_column**.

From the documentation:

**feature_column.embedding_column** - 
`DenseColumn` that converts from sparse, categorical input.
  Use this when your inputs are sparse, but you want to convert them to a dense
  representation (e.g., to feed to a DNN).

**keras.layers.Embedding** - Turns positive integers (indexes) into dense vectors of fixed size.
  e.g. `[[4], [20]] -> [[0.25, 0.1], [0.6, -0.2]]`
  This layer can only be used as the first layer in a model.

My question is, is both of the api doing similar thing on different type of input data(for ex. input - [0,1,2] for keras.layers.Embedding and its one-hot-encoded rep. [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1] for feature_column.embedding_column)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reviewing source code for both operations here is what I found:

- both operations rely on `tensorflow.python.ops.embedding_ops` funcitonality;
- keras.layers.Embedding uses **dense** representations and contains generic keras code for fiddling with shapes, init variables etc;
- feature_column.embedding_column relies on **sparse** and contains functionality to cache results.

So, your guess seems to be right: these 2 are doing similar things, rely on distinct input representations, contain some logic that doesn't change the essense of what they do.